# how to get total of all column if GridView Paging is set as “True”?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

this code display total of column in each page of grid view footer I want to display total of all columns in all pages footer

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string deb = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("debit")).Text;
        string cred = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("credit")).Text;

        decimal totalvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(deb) - Convert.ToDecimal(cred);

        amount += totalvalue;

        Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
        lbl.Text = amount.ToString();

        Label lblDebAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("debit");
        Label lblCredamount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("credit");

        float debtotal = (float)Decimal.Parse(lblDebAmount.Text);
        float credtotal = (float)Decimal.Parse(lblCredamount.Text);
        totalPriced += debtotal;
        totalPricec += credtotal;

        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label totallblCAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblDebAmount");
            Label totallblCredAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblCredAmount");
            totallblCAmount.Text = totalPriced.ToString("###,###.000");
           totallblCredAmount.Text = totalPricec.ToString("###,###.000");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do it when the row is data bound? Why not do it when you originally bind the data?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = Database.GetData();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        //calculate here by manually adding up the debit/credit column from dt
        //or do a separate database call that calculates the sum, ex: select sum(debits), sum(credits) from general_ledger
    }
}
```

It makes sense to let the database do the math calculation for you. You wouldn't need to write your own custom calculation code. Just let the database's `sum` function handle it.

---

Here's a little more detail.

```
//Executes a SqlCommand and returns a DataTable
public class GetDataTable(SqlCommand command)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
    }
    return dt;
}

//Executes a SqlCommand and returns a scalar of type T
public static T GetScalar<T>(SqlCommand command)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection ("connectionstring"))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result is T)
        {
            return (T)result;
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
        }
    }
}

//Load the data into the GridView, then get the credit amount and put the value in a label.
//You'll need to adjust the queries to match your schema
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        var tableCommand = new SqlCommand("select columns from table");
        GridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable(tableCommand);
        GridView1.DataBind();
        var creditCommand = new SqlCommand("select sum(stat_amount) from tablename where stat_flag='c'");
        var credits = GetScalar<decimal>(creditCommand);
        Label1.Text = credits;        
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because I only have amount table and flag and I dispaly credit and debet in grid view by doing this in html

Comment: @feby I don't understand your last comment. Can you please explain better?

Comment: in data base I only have stat_amount that include the credit and debit and I have also stat_flag that include d and c in Html :    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="credt">
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <div style="padding:0 0 5px 0"><asp:Label ID="credit" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="c" ) ? string.Format("{0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("stat_amount").ToString())): "0.00" %>'></asp:Label></div>
                </ItemTemplate>

Comment: @feby So? That shouldn't prevent you from using my answer. `select sum(stat_amount) from tablename where stat_flag='c'`. Assign the results of that query to a label.

Comment: but I am using parameters so  I think I can't put it in load page  SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[4];para[0] = new SqlParameter("stat_sub_leger", ddlACCcode.SelectedValue);
   para[1] = new SqlParameter("branch", DDLBranch.SelectedValue);para[2] = new SqlParameter("from", txtFrom.Text);para[3] = new SqlParameter("to", txtTo.Text);
DataTable dtreport = db.SelectCmdText("Select * from PostedVoucher join transactions on trans_code = stat_trans_code where stat_sub_leger = stat_sub_leger and branch=branch and stat_date between from and to ORDER BY stat_date ", para);

Comment: select statement how to call it in footer ??

Comment: @feby You don't call it "in the footer". You call it in your function's page load method, and assign the result to a label that is in the footer.